# How to update the phonegap 2.9.0 to 3.0 or hide the status bar in phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

am having problem in my app i.e the status bar shows, if  the status bar shows means footer alignment will be disappear some of the google search upgrade the phonegap version to 3.0 and i dont know how to upgrade it  to 3.0 version.is any possible to hide it via javascript.please help me this is my first app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify full-screen true similar to this in the config.xml of the project.
`<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

Have a look here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem when using phonegap with xcode / iOS...
To hide the status bar for iOS7 in xcode apps I do the following:

in AppDelegate.m within the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: add

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

and in .plist file add two rows:

```
Status bar is initially hidden YES
View controller-based status bar appearance NO
```

I am using Phonegap 3.0 CLI, I would assume being native code this should also work for 2.9.

I do also thoroughly recommend spending the time to read through how to setup Phonegap CLI on your machine. It may take a little while to understand the new process but once you get there you would NEVER go back ;)
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface